# jqgrid ellipsis

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In jqGrid, is there a native way to show "..." at the end of a column if it's text did not fit and was truncated?

I see that there is a ui-ellipsis class but I'm confused as to if it's automatically added if the text is truncated and if it goes away automatically once the column is resized?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can solve the problem using the following CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td { text-overflow: ellipsis;-o-text-overflow: ellipsis; }
</style>
```

In the case you will have the results like displayed below:

[image]

(see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithEllipsis.htm) live)

In some other situations another CSS style would be better:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
        white-space: normal !important;
        height:auto;
        vertical-align:middle;
        padding-top:3px;
        padding-bottom:3px
    }
</style>
```

In the case the results are the following:

[image]

(see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithWrapping.htm) live).

Both above settings are my common settings which I use frequently depended on the customers requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
fit text plugin:

 (function($) {
        $.fn.fitText = function(options) {
            options = $.extend({
                width: 0,
                height: 0
            }, options);

            $(this).each(function() {
                var elem = $(this);
                if (options.height > 0) {
                    while (elem.height() > options.height) {
                        elem.text(elem.text().substring(0, (elem.text().length - 4)) + "...");
                    }
                }
                if (options.width > 0) {
                    while (elem.width() > options.width) {
                        elem.text(elem.text().substring(0, (elem.text().length - 4)) + "...");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })(jQuery);


calling the function:

    $('.ADHrefUserName').fitText({ width: 200, height: 25 });
```

Comment: So I guess you are saying no, there is not a native way?