# jqGrid 4.5.2 - formatting bug

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

We recently upgraded from jqGrid 4.4.1 to jqGrid 4.5.2 and noticed that some of our cell formatting is no longer working.

We previously had a formatter function defined as

```
function addEllipsis(cellvalue) {
    return '<div class="ellipsis" title="' + cellvalue + '">' + cellvalue + '</div>';
}
```

We would use this in our colModel, for example,

```
colModel = [
{
  name: "longText",
  label: "longText",
  formatter: addEllipsis
},
...
]
```

However, the formatter is no longer working - the ellipsis is not being added to the cells. When I downgrade to jqGrid 4.4.3 it works fine. But upgrading to >= 4.5.2 causes the ellipsis to go away.

Is this a bug in the 4.5 releases?

**Update:** Here is the CSS for the ellipsis class.

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -moz-binding: url('assets/xml/ellipsis.xml#ellipsis');
}
```

Comment: How you defined CSS rules using the class `ellipsis`? Why you need to use custom formatters at all for the column?

Comment: Hi Oleg, good to hear from you. I updated the post to include the CSS for the ellipsis class. Regarding your comment, is there an easy way to do this without custom formatters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement ellipsis in jqGrid in a little other way. In [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithEllipsis.htm) created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6861490/315935) I used *more specific* CSS rule which allows to place ellipsis in all columns of the grid.

[The new demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TextWithEllipsis.htm) uses `classes: "ellipsis"` property in `colModel`. It allows to places `ellipsis` class on `<td>` elements of *specific* columns. I used the CSS rule

```css
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

The main advantage of the approach: **you don't need to use custom formatters**. In the demo I combined `formatter: "date"` with `classes: "ellipsis"` and you can see the following picture as the result

[image]

So I don't think that the described problem is a bug in jqGrid 4.5.2. I think that you should just adjust your CSS rule and remove custom formatter which you use currently.

Comment: Thank you, this is a neat way of doing it. Your presence on these forums is much appreciated :-)

Comment: @ktm5124: You are welcome! I'm glad that you find my old answers helpful too.