# Jqgrid Formatting for lengthy text

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How would I take text that is too long, and shorten it within a jquery grid, allowing the user to click on text, or an icon to display the rest of the text within a popup window?

Attached is a picture that shows what happens, and what I would like to do.

Looking to learn from this, not just an answer, but documentation, examples, etc.

Thanks!
[image: Example]

Comment: display: block; white-space: no-wrap;  overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis

Comment: Look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6861490/315935)